# Does anyone know this aquatic plant?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

[image]

Does anyone know this plants? And will it grow sideways?

Comment: There are min two different plants I can see... Which one? You should try biology.SE for identifications.

Comment: Both. Oh I see.